# How can I use a trigger to allow an incremented, user-assigned ID?

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I am moving a small database from MS Access into SQL Server. Each year, the users would create a new Access database and have clean data, but this change will put data across the years into one pot. The users have relied on the autonumber value in Access as a reference for records. That is very inaccurate if, say, 238 records are removed.

So I am trying to accommodate them with an id column they can control (somewhat). They will not see the real primary key in the SQL table, but I want to give them an ID they can edit, but still be unique.

I've been working with this trigger, but it has taken much longer than I expected.

Everything SEEMS TO work fine, except I don't understand why I have the same data in my INSERTED table as the table the trigger is on. (See note in code.)

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_tblAppData] 
   ON  [dbo].[tblAppData] 
   AFTER INSERT,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @NewUserEnteredId int = 0;
    DECLARE @RowIdForUpdate int = 0;
    DECLARE @CurrentUserEnteredId int = 0;

    DECLARE @LoopCount int = 0;

    --*** Loop through all records to be updated because the values will be incremented.
    WHILE (1 = 1)
    BEGIN
        SET @LoopCount = @LoopCount + 1;

        IF (@LoopCount > (SELECT Count(*) FROM INSERTED))
            BREAK;

        SELECT TOP 1 @RowIdForUpdate = ID, @CurrentUserEnteredId = UserEnteredId FROM INSERTED WHERE ID > @RowIdForUpdate ORDER BY ID DESC;

        IF (@RowIdForUpdate IS NULL)
            BREAK;

        -- WHY IS THERE A MATCH HERE? HAS THE RECORD ALREADY BEEN INSERTED?
        IF EXISTS (SELECT UserEnteredId FROM tblAppData WHERE UserEnteredId = @CurrentUserEnteredId)
        BEGIN
            SET @NewUserEnteredId = (SELECT Max(t1.UserEnteredId) + 1 FROM tblAppData t1);
        END
        ELSE
            SET @NewUserEnteredId = @CurrentUserEnteredId;

        UPDATE tblAppData
        SET UserEnteredId = @NewUserEnteredId
        FROM tblAppData a
        WHERE a.ID = @RowIdForUpdate

    END
END
```

Here is what I want to accomplish:

1. When new record(s) are added, it should increment values from the Max existing
2. When a user overrides a value, it should check to see the existence of that value. If found restore the existing value, otherwise allow the change.

This trigger allows for multiple rows being added at a time.

It is great for this to be efficient for future use, but in reality, they will only add 1,000 records a year.

Comment: Why do the users need to edit this number? It makes no sense. What you are proposing is a very bad idea indeed. You are attempting to roll your own identity property through a trigger with a loop. What is the benefit? If you delete the same 238 rows from the middle you still have the "hole". And who cares? Gaps in sequential numbers are perfectly normal and make sense because of deletes. I think both you and the users have put too much emphasis on what should be just a number.

Comment: how about simply concatenating year and their ID together.

Comment: The year and ID is a great idea (I might work that in) but I'm hoping for the ID to be pre-populated by the most recently used value, not the IDENTITY column value.

Comment: @AndyInNC did you get what you needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't use a trigger to accomplish this.

Here is a script you can use to create a sequence (op didn't tag version), create the primary key, use the sequence as your special id, and put a constraint on the column.

```
create table dbo.test (
    testid      int identity(1,1) not null primary key clustered 
,   myid        int null constraint UQ_ unique 
,   somevalue   nvarchar(255) null
);

create sequence dbo.myid
as int
 start with 1
 increment by 1;

 alter table dbo.test
    add default next value for dbo.myid for myid;

insert into dbo.test (somevalue)

select 'this' union all
select 'that' union all
select 'and' union all
select 'this';

insert into dbo.test (myid, somevalue)

select 33, 'oops';

select *
  from dbo.test

insert into dbo.test (somevalue)

select 'oh the fun';

select *
  from dbo.test
--| This should error
insert into dbo.test (myid, somevalue)

select 3, 'This is NO fun';
```

Here is the result set:

```
testid  myid    somevalue
1       1       this
2       2       that
3       3       and
4       4       this
5       33      oops
6       5       oh the fun
```

And at the very end a test, which will error.

Comment: First of all, I've never heard of the Sequence / Next value for syntax until now! It seems to work, except when I tested in SSMS (table edit window), it gave an error because the edit window defaults to TOP 200. (For some reason it doesn't like TOP n with a constraint.)

Comment: There are some interesting niche things you can do with it, one of the fundamental designs is to use it across database objects where  you would like to have a single control key.